# How to update element in activity on another class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

i have the problem when i want to update element in activity with intent.actually i can getparams and set to element..but the problem is when i'm not using intent i'm using method to set value of my element ..this is my code

this code i'm place in ChatActivity.java

```
/*
     * set element attribute
     */

    public void setAttr(String value){
            welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWelcome);
        welcome.setText("welcome " + value);
    }
```

and i'm call that code in another class , that class is ProcessChat.java

```
public void welcome(){

ChatActivity chat = new ChatActivity();
chat.setAttr("user");
}
```

when i'm run i'm get the error java.lang.null....
what's wrong ? how ican fix this..
thanks for your answer..

Comment: Can you post the error in Logcat??

Comment: actually the error is java.lang.null.PointerExceptionist...i'm call method setAttr without intent to chatActivity...but another method call intent to load data and show data in chatActivity,my problem just not update data without call intent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following code to create new intent in ProcessChat

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
i.putExtra("value", "This value one for ChatActivity ");
startActivity(Intent)
```

Put this code in OnCreate method of ChatActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
        return;
        }
// Get data via the key
String value = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value != null) {
    setAttr(value)
}
```

OR

put following code before `welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWelcome)`

```
this.setContentView(<layout>)
```

Comment: actually if i'm using intent is work...but in my case i don't use intent..because if i'm use two intent in two condition in one activity , the first intent will be replace in the second condition of inten,so my data in first inten lost.. but i need both of data is show..thanks you

Comment: then try to implement MVC architecture. store data on third class like Application class. then onResume get data and display it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line `welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWelcome);`

`findViewById` **is used to define a view not to create a view** I think you are calling that methos before creating the view. so it returns null method. Make sure that the view is defined and hence findviewbyid will give you a not null value then only set any value.

Comment: yes, i think so...because that code not define to onCreate...but i'm confuse to define that code if i'm call in another class..